# 1:N relationship query to find one in Sequelize.js not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have started learning sequelize.js with node.js and having hard time defining relationships between models. I am trying to create `1:N relationship` between `users` and `roles` tables i.e. many users can have same role.

**Problem**

When I query user model to test the defined relation ship it gives me error that `original: error: column "RoleId" does not exist`.

**roles model:**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Role extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Role.hasMany(models.User, {as: 'users'});
    }
  }
  Role.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    } 
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Role',
    tableName: 'roles',
  });
  return Role;
};
```

**users model:**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      // User.belongsTo(models.Role, {foreignKey: 'roleId', as: 'role'});
      User.belongsTo(models.Role);
    }
  }
  User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    mobile: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
    // },
    // roleId: {
    //   type: DataTypes.STRING,
    //   allowNull: false
    // }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'users',
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

**relationship tester js code:**

```
const { User, Role } = require('./models');

User.findOne({
    where: {email: 'admin@papertrader.org'}
  })
  .then((findedUser) => {
    console.log(findedUser)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error while find user : ", err)
  });
```

[image: Output]

Can anyone one please guide me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you check if it could be a sync issue (like some `roleId` column still existing in the database table but not in the User model)?

Comment: I dropped the database and ran all migrations again but problem still exists. I can see roleId column in my users table with pgAdmin tool.

Comment: Did you check also case-sensitivity issues? I use mostly mySQL but I remember that postgreSQL columns are case-sensitive when in double quotes. (and the SELECT query is "RoleId", not "roleId")

Comment: Let me check. I hope that's not the case with sequelize or postgresql.

Comment: @cheesyMan, you are right, postgresQL table column names are case sensitive.